# NaN issue in aura:method

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-method

I have a `aura:method` the return value from parent is `NaN`.

Why is my code returning `NaN`?

**child component**

```
<aura:method name="myAction"
                 action="{!c.myAction}"
                   access="public">
       <aura:attribute name="num1" 
       <aura:attribute name="num2" 
        var params=event.getParam("arguments");
        if (params)
        {
           var par1=params.num1;
            var par2=params.num2;
            var output=parseInt(par1)+parseInt(par2);}
```

Inside the parent component I have like this as below

```
 <c:AuraMethodChild aura:id="ChildComp"/>
 <lightning:button label="ClickMe"
                    onclick="{!c.ClickMe}"/>
 var findchild = component.find('ChildComp');
 var rtnMsgFromChildMethod = parseInt(findchild.myAction());
```

Comment: You're going to need to include more code (beyond what you just edited out) to get clarity on this.

Comment: Inside the child comp <aura:method name="myAction" action="{!c.myAction}"  access="public">
 <aura:attribute name="num1" type="integer" default="20"/>
 <aura:attribute name="num2" type="integer" default="30"/>

Comment: In child comp controller: var params=event.getParam("arguments");
if (params)  { var par1=params.num1; var par2=params.num2;  var output=parseInt(par1)+parseInt(par2);}component.set("v.prntoutput",output);

Comment: please **[edit]** your post rather than adding up in the comments

Comment: Does your event handler return strings that are integer values? If not, that would explain the cause of your issue. Could also be that it's it's only returning one of the values, in which case the other one wouldn't be defined and the sum would be NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning result from the ChildComp controller method. Use below after 
closing of if statement

```
return output;
```

Check Salesforce Doc 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cmp_methods_sync.htm

Comment: thanks very much. I was not returning the value. It worked..